# Merge rows when twocolumns have matches in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as ;

```
Species   Family  Events  Groups
Monkey    A       6,7     G1,G2
Monkey    A,B     6,8,9   G1,G2,G4,G8,G12
Elephant  B       7,8     G6,G7
Elephant  C       9,10    G6
Dog       K       10      G90
Dog       L,M,N   8,10,9  G90,G91
```

and the idea is to merge within `Species`, columbs where at least there is match between `Events` and `Groups` columns.

For instance in `Monkey`:

```
Species   Family  Events  Groups
Monkey    A       6,7     G1,G2
Monkey    A,B     6,8,9   G1,G2,G4,G8,G12
```

`Event 6` and `Groups G1` in **row1** is also in **row2*, so I merge them :

```
Species   Family  Events  Groups
Monkey    A,B       6,7,8,9 G1,G2,G4,G8,G12
```

At the end the expect output would be :

```
Species   Family  Events  Groups
Monkey    A,B     6,7,8,9 G1,G2,G4,G8,G12
Elephant  B       7,8     G6,G7
Elephant  C       9,10    G6
Dog       K,L,M,N   8,9,10  G90,G91
```

I did not merge Elephant since there is not match in `Events` columns.

Does someone have an idea of code please, thank you.

here are the data :

```
structure(list(Species = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Dog", 
"Elephant", "Monkey"), class = "factor"), Family = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", 
"A,B", "B", "C", "K", "L,M,N"), class = "factor"), Events = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("10", "6,7", "6,8,9", "7,8", 
"8,10,9", "9,10"), class = "factor"), Groups = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c(" G1,G2", " G6,G7", "G1,G2,G4,G8,G12", 
"G6", "G90", "G90,G91"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: 1) separate, 2) pivot_longer 3) filter those with max(n()) >1, 4) tostring those records and 5) merge these with unfiltered records.

Comment: Was a mistake sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this strategy

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Family, Events, Groups), ~as.character(.))) %>%
  summarise(across(c(Events, Groups), ~ toString(Reduce(intersect, strsplit(., ','))))) %>%
  filter(Events != "" & Groups != "") %>%
  select(Species) 

df1 %>%
  left_join(df %>% mutate(across(c(Family, Events, Groups), ~as.character(.)))) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(c(Family, Events, Groups), ~ toString(Reduce(union, strsplit(., ','))))) %>%
  rbind(df %>% anti_join(df1))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Species  Family     Events     Groups             
  <fct>    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>              
1 Dog      K, L, M, N 10, 8, 9   G90, G91           
2 Monkey   A, B       6, 7, 8, 9 G1, G2, G4, G8, G12
3 Elephant B          7,8        G6,G7              
4 Elephant C          9,10       G6
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much for this and your time !!!  It helped a lot. I also have another similar issue, maybe you can help as well ?? Here is the post if you have the time : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475914/merge-rows-within-a-dataframe-where-several-columns-contains-at-least-one-duplic?noredirect=1#comment117522228_66475914