# Merge rows when element coma separated found in another row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Hello I have a dataframe such as :

```
  species family    Events      groups
1     SP1      A     10,22          G1
2     SP1      B         7          G2
3     SP1    C,D 4,5,6,1,3 G3,G4,G5,G6
4     SP2      A     22,10          G1
5     SP2    D,C 6,5,4,3,1 G4,G6,G5,G3
6     SP3      C 4,5,3,6,1    G3,G6,G5
7     SP3      E         7          G2
8     SP3      A        10          G1
9     SP4      C        7,22        G12
```

and I would like to simply merge row for each where there is at least one duplicated element in each columns (except `species`).

For instance I will merge the rows :

```
species family    Events      groups
SP1      A        10,22       G1
species family    Events      groups
SP2      A        22,10       G1
species family    Events      groups
SP3      A        10          G1
```

into

```
species      family    Events      groups
SP1,SP2,SP3  A         10,22       G1
```

SO if I do the same for each row I should get an expected output as :

```
species      family    Events      groups
SP1,SP2,SP3  A         10,22       G1
SP1,SP3      B,E       7           G2
SP1,SP2,SP3  C,D       1,3,4,5,6   G3,G4,G6,G5
SP4          C         7,22        G12
```

Note that SP4 has not been merged with any rows since its group was not present in any other rows.

Does someone have an idea please ?
Thank you very much for your help and time

Here is the dataframe if it can helps:

```
structure(list(species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3", "SP4"), class = "factor"), 
    family = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "C,D", "D,C", "E"), class = "factor"), Events = structure(c(2L, 
    7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 8L), .Label = c("10", "10,22", 
    "22,10", "4,5,3,6,1", "4,5,6,1,3", "6,5,4,3,1", "7", "7,22"
    ), class = "factor"), groups = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("G1", "G12", "G2", "G3,G4,G5,G6", 
    "G3,G6,G5", "G4,G6,G5,G3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

**What I can do and tried :**

So far I only know how to merge rows with exact duplicated value using something like that in dplyr :

```
desired_df <- df %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-species)) %>%
  summarize(species = toString(species)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(names(df))
```

but here we do not have exact duplicated values, instead I'm looking for between `comma` that can be present in another row.

Comment: what if there is a row which has Events "7, 22". Where should we put this row? To the rows 10, 22 or to 7 or both?

Comment: Hello @Roman, I added an exemple, if there is no duplicated values within all columns '''(family,    Events,      groups)''', then I do not merge.

Comment: But you still might get the case where there is a duplicated value within all columns for two separate groups. For example `SP4; A,B; 7,22; G1,G2`. Is this a case you might encounter? If so it could be merged with potentially row 1 or row 2

Comment: Ho ok I see, well this case cannot exist since the algo I use before that step does not allow such cases.

Comment: does someone have any idea ?

Comment: I tried a little bit but won't have any more time to look at it until later today.

Comment: @qdread no problemo thank you :)

Comment: Maybe you can try to explain how you would do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an all-tidyverse solution (calling the input data frame `dat`).

**Please note that this solution is not identical to the desired output you gave.** This is because you stated the rule is to "merge rows for which there is at least one duplicated element for each column, except species." By that rule, rows 2 and 7 should not be merged because they share no `family` in common.

First, convert the three columns we are going to test for overlapping values into list-columns. Now each element of those columns is a list. I also coerced the `Events` column to a numeric so that it will sort properly.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(across(c(family, Events, groups), ~ strsplit(as.character(.), split = ','))) %>%
  mutate(Events = map(Events, as.numeric))
```

Next, define a function to collapse each row of the data frame. The function takes argument `i` which is a row index. Within the function, we do two things:

- First we use `pmap_lgl` to iterate across each row of the data frame to check for which rows all the three columns `family`, `Events`, and `groups` have at least one shared value with row `i` and therefore should be collapsed. For example, if `i==1` this will return `TRUE` for rows 1,4,and 8.
- Next, we filter `dat` for only those rows that returned `TRUE`, and apply a function to all columns of those rows. The function collapses all columns in those rows into comma-separated strings of the sorted unique values.

```
collapse_rows <- function(i) {
  rows_collapse <- pmap_lgl(dat, function(family, Events, groups, ...) 
    any(dat$family[[i]] %in% family) & any(dat$Events[[i]] %in% Events) & any(dat$groups[[i]] %in% groups))
  dat %>%
    filter(rows_collapse) %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ paste(sort(unique(unlist(.))), collapse = ',')))
}
```

Finally we apply this function to each row index. We end up with duplicated rows, for example rows 1, 4, and 8 of the initial output will be identical. We use `distinct` to remove all of those duplicates.

```
dat_collapse <- map_dfr(1:nrow(dat), collapse_rows) %>% distinct
```

Final output:

```
     species family    Events      groups
1 SP1,SP2,SP3      A     10,22          G1
2         SP1      B         7          G2
3 SP1,SP2,SP3    C,D 1,3,4,5,6 G3,G4,G5,G6
4         SP3      E         7          G2
5         SP4      C      7,22         G12
```

Comment: Wow, thank you veru much for this and for your time !!